# For .. in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a question regarding for..in (for loop) in Objective-C

below is my header and implementation file:

==header==

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;
@property(nonatomic, getter = isMatched) BOOL matched;
@property(nonatomic, getter = isChosen) BOOL chosen;


-(int)match: (NSArray *)otherCards;

@end
```

==implementation==

```
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card

-(int)match: (NSArray *) otherCards{
    int score =0;

    for(Card* card in otherCards){
        if ([card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents]) {
            score =1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
@end
```

1. In the implementation file (inside the for loop), what does the self in self.contents referring to ?
2. Does the for loop intend to compare one card in the array to the rest of the other cards in the array?
3. How would you write the loop in the conventional iteration `for(int i=0, i<n; i++)`.
   Assuming n is the size of the loop

Thank you

Comment: If you don't know what "self" is you've not studied the Objective-C language ***at all*** and you should not be programming in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The card that received the `match` message.

2) No, it compares one card (`self`) with an array of cards (`otherCards`).

3) Here's the equivalent code using an index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [otherCards count]; i++)
    if([otherCards[i].contents isEqualToString:self.contents]) {
        score = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this method's argument is only the array, it doesn't specify the content of the card in self. How do I know what is inside the self.contents ?

Comment: @dodgerblue - You have the source for the `Card` class there in front of you.  What does it say `contents` is?

Comment: @HotLicks `contents` will be filled with the suits and ranks of a Playing Card. There will be another class named Playing Card that inherits from this Card class.

Comment: @dodgerblue - So why did you ask what's in `contents`?

Comment: @dodgerblue Every instance method has a hidden parameter called `self`. You really need to take a step back and make sure that you're up to speed on OOP basics. I'm assuming you're going through the CS193P lectures. Are you familiar with all the concepts in CS108? If not, start there instead.

Comment: @godel9 You're right. I've taken OOP in C++ in my community college. Aced the class but barely learned anything about OOP. Thanks I'd rather step back to CS108

Comment: @dodgerblue - Yes, just about every OO language has a concept of "self" or "this" that is a pseudo-variable pointing to the current object.  So if you invoke `[somePointer someMethod]`, inside `someMethod` you can use "self" to refer to the value that was in "somePointer" in the call.

Answer (score 1):

1. `self` refers to the object that the `match` method was called on. self.contents refers to this property defined in your header: `@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;`
2. The loop compares all of the cards in the array otherCard to the card that the match message was sent to.

3.

```
for(int i=0; i< [otherCards count]; i++)
{
    if ([otherCards[i].contents isEqualToString:self.contents]) 
    {
        score =1;
    }
}
```